# NSTimer UILabel not updating in MonoTouch

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, uilabel, nstimer

I am trying to update an UILabel within an NSTimer.

```
LoadingOverlay.Hidden = false; 
NSTimer.CreateScheduledTimer(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 1),     
delegate {Callback(obj); LoadingOverlay.Hidden = true;};
```

I want to update the UILabel within the Callback, but it does not work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use InvokeOnMainThread to execute your UI changes on the UI thread.

```
InvokeOnMainThread(delegate{
    LoadingOverlay.Hidden = true;
});
```